# How to line up ui elements using style argument in shiny app that uses bslib 5

Tags: css, r, shiny, bslib

I developed a shiny app ui layout that works with bslib 4, but when I switch to bslib 5 my formatting falls apart. I'm not sure why?

Here is my code

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

ui <- navbarPage("My App",
                 id = "navbar",

  theme = bslib::bs_theme(version = 4, #setting bootstrap version
                          bootswatch = "darkly",
                          base_font = "roboto",
                          font_scale = 1.2),

  tabPanel("TAB 1",
           fluidPage(
               fluidRow(selectInput("dataset", label = "Dataset",
                                    choices = ls("package:datasets")),
                        actionButton("enter", label = "confirm choice",
                                     style = "margin-top: 32px; height: 38px; margin-left: 10px;"
                        )
               ),
               verbatimTextOutput("summary"),
               tableOutput("table")
             )
  ),
  tabPanel("TAB 2",
           h3("bla bla"))
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

when using bslib 4 it looks like this

[image]

but when I use bslib 5 it looks like this

[image]

How can I align buttons in bslib 5? I'd like to use `bslib::card()` in the results part of the app so I need bslib 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `style` argument: `style = "margin-top: 35px; margin-left: 10px; height: 38px;"`

`div()` function  creates a container element for `selectInput` and `actionButton`.

With the `class` argument we can assign CSS classes to the `div` element for adding styles to the container.

By adding the Bootstrap class `d-flex` class the container we can use flexbox layout.

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

ui <- navbarPage(
  "My App",
  id = "navbar",
  theme = bs_theme(
    version = 5,
    bootswatch = "darkly",
    base_font = "roboto",
    font_scale = 1.2
  ),
  tabPanel(
    "TAB 1",
    fluidPage(
      fluidRow(
        div(
          class = "d-flex",
          style = "margin-top: 32px;",
          selectInput(
            "dataset",
            label = "Dataset",
            choices = ls("package:datasets")
          ),
          actionButton(
            "enter",
            label = "Confirm Choice",
            style = "margin-top: 35px; margin-left: 10px; height: 38px;"
          )
        )
      ),
      verbatimTextOutput("summary"),
      tableOutput("table")
    )
  ),
  tabPanel("TAB 2", h3("bla bla"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! could you explain the `div()` class argument?

Answer (score 2):

In your `fluidRow`, you can add:

`style = "display: flex; flex-wrap: nowrap; width: min-content;"`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. What does this do?

Comment: it creates a 'flex' container, sets the alignment of items within it to be placed side by side, and then sets the width of the container to not take the full horizontal space. You can read more about it if interested https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/